# PM2 dump vs ecosystem.json

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am configuring production infrastructure for node.js with pm2 and I am stuck with the relation between `ecosystem.json` file and `pm2 save` command that writes some sort of dump file. As far as I understood the contents of that dump file will be used by pm2 in case server reboots.

Is it possible to pass an `ecosystem.json` file to pm2 startup script so that it acts much like a config file (something like nginx.conf for nginx) instead? I don't like the idea that the state after restart will be picked app from the dump file that is not in readable/editable format.

Or I'm missing the point of PM2 configuration?

Comment: I also wants to create node js build for production mode, I am using enclose module for build creation, How can I integrate PM2 in it?